# Суммирование данных preg_match_all

Tags: php

Всем привет!
Жутко подтупливаю, есть функция поиска слов в тексте, произвожу поиск по циклу, после если слова нашлись, мне нужно получить сумму всех найденных слов, но что-то я не могу понять как это сделать. Код снизу, вопрос как суммировать $result найденных данных?

```
$url = "В разделе отдельные промышленные металлодекторы интернет-магазина  представлено оборудование от ведущих мировых производителей.";
$filt = array ('промышленные','мировых,оборудование');
function txtsearch($url, $filt) { 

foreach ($filt as $filter)
    { preg_match_all("/(?<![\w\d])$filter(?![\w\d])/siu", mb_strtolower($url), $result);
        echo $result;
    }
    }
```

Comment: разве в `$result[0]` уже не будет результирующий набор который можно посчитать через `count` ?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c0a106c2fc6bb0ac568110ae7a2b344f7d0cba9

Comment: А вообще что значить сумма всех найденных слов? Кол-во что ли?

Comment: $sum += count($result[0]);

Comment: Дополнил код для понимания, через count не получиться вывести сумму всех вхождений, происходит перебор и поиск всех данных массива в тексте.

Comment: Зачем вообще дёргать count, если preg_match_all сам по себе возвращает число найденных вхождений? В чём же заключается вопрос - понятнее не стало

Comment: В том, что у меня проходит цикл и считает вхождение всех фраз в тексте, получается на выходе данные, к пример: 6 раз встретился, 5 раз встретился, 2 раза встретился, вот мне эти данные и нужно суммировать.

Comment: делайте ассоциативный массив. и в цикле буквально `$array[$resilt[0]]++` (ну только явно создавайте элементы для первого найденного, если в php это требуется) после цикла пробегаетесь foreach по полученному массиву и спокойно печатаете количества из него.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, надо всего лишь воспользоваться **[array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php)** для подсчёта.

Ну и сделать косметическую правку в виде `implode('|', $filterArr)`.

Пример:

```
$text = <<<TEXT
В разделе отдельные промышленные промышленные промышленные 
металлодекторы интернет-магазина  
представлено оборудование от ведущих мировых производителей. супер пупер мировых производителей!
TEXT;

$filterArr = array('промышленные','мировых','оборудование');

preg_match_all("/(?<![\w\d])".implode('|', $filterArr)."(?![\w\d])/siu", mb_strtolower($text), $searchResult);

$filterCountValues = array_count_values($searchResult[0]);

foreach ($filterCountValues as $word => $count) {
    echo 'слово "' . $word . '" встретилось ' . $count . ' раз(а) <br/>';
}
```

В `$searchResult[0]` будет массив:

```
    Array (
        [0] => промышленные
        [1] => промышленные
        [2] => промышленные
        [3] => оборудование
        [4] => мировых
        [5] => мировых
    )
```

Вывод:

```
слово "промышленные" встретилось 3 раз(а) 
слово "оборудование" встретилось 1 раз(а) 
слово "мировых" встретилось 2 раз(а)
```

---

P.S. Возможно нужен вывод количества раз всех слов, даже если они не встречались, тогда цикл такой:

```
foreach ($filterArr as $word) {
    $tpl = 'слово "' . $word . '" встретилось ';    
    $tpl .= isset($filterCountValues[$word]) ? $filterCountValues[$word] : 0;    
    $tpl .= ' раз(а) <br/>';

    echo $tpl;
}
```

Comment: Всем спасибо, я затупил и вопрос не очень правильно задал. Вопрос свой решил!

Answer (score 0):

```
function txtsearch($url, $filt) { 

 $count_txtsearch = 0;
foreach ($filt as $filter)
    {
        preg_match("/(?<![\w\d])$filter(?![\w\d])/siu", mb_strtolower($url), $result);

        $count_txt = count($result);            
        $count_txtsearch+=$count_txt;           

    }
        if ( $count_txtsearch > 0) {
        return 1;
        } else {
        return 0;    
        }
    }
```